# Hover data does not show up in plotly graph

Tags: python, hover, plotly

I would like to have a radar plot that is filled and have information on hover. I only get one of it working. Here is an example:

Let us assume we have unpivoted data:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'sample':['sample_1','sample_2','sample_3','sample_1','sample_2','sample_3','sample_1','sample_2','sample_3'],
                  'KPI':['KPI_1','KPI_1','KPI_1','KPI_2','KPI_2','KPI_2','KPI_3','KPI_3','KPI_3'],
                  'value':[1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1],
                  'sample_info':['info_1','info_1','info_1','info_2','info_2','info_2','info_3','info_3','info_3']})
df
    sample      KPI     value   sample_info
0   sample_1    KPI_1   1   info_1
1   sample_2    KPI_1   2   info_1
2   sample_3    KPI_1   1   info_1
3   sample_1    KPI_2   1   info_2
4   sample_2    KPI_2   1   info_2
5   sample_3    KPI_2   2   info_2
6   sample_1    KPI_3   2   info_3
7   sample_2    KPI_3   1   info_3
8   sample_3    KPI_3   1   info_3
```

I want to have a radar plot with the `sample_info` on hover, like this:

```
fig = px.line_polar(df, r='value', theta='KPI', color='sample',line_close = True,
                   hover_data = ['sample_info'])
fig.show()
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDpsx.png)

That works fine. Now I would like to fill the graph:

```
fig = px.line_polar(df, r='value', theta='KPI', color='sample',line_close = True,
                   hover_data = ['sample_info'])
fig.update_traces(fill='toself')
fig.show()
```

Now, the hover information is somehow overwritten. I tried it with custom_data and a hovertemplate:

```
fig = px.line_polar(df, r='value', theta='KPI', color='sample',line_close = True,
                   custom_data = ['sample_info'])
fig.update_traces(fill='toself',hovertemplate="'sample_info: %{customdata[0]}'")
fig.show()
```

but without success. What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(hoveron='points'))
```

And get:

[image]

#### Complete code:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

df = pd.DataFrame({'sample':['sample_1','sample_2','sample_3','sample_1','sample_2','sample_3','sample_1','sample_2','sample_3'],
                  'KPI':['KPI_1','KPI_1','KPI_1','KPI_2','KPI_2','KPI_2','KPI_3','KPI_3','KPI_3'],
                  'value':[1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1],
                  'sample_info':['info_1','info_1','info_1','info_2','info_2','info_2','info_3','info_3','info_3']})

fig = px.line_polar(df, r='value', theta='KPI', color='sample',line_close = True,
                   hover_data = ['sample_info'])
fig.update_traces(fill='toself')

fig.for_each_trace(lambda t: t.update(hoveron='points'))

fig.show()
```

Comment: Thanks, that works for hover over points and would solve my problem. When I add ```hoveron='points+fills'```  to get the hover information also when I hover over fills it does not work. I get different hover information. The desired one for points and a default one for fills. Is there a possibility to have the same for both?